# Using jackson-dataformat-xml on Websphere

Tags: java, maven, websphere, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm trying to read an XML from String using jackson-dataformat-xml :

```
String data = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"+
            "<aa>"+
            "<bb>bb</bb>"+
            "</aa>";

XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(data.getBytes());
```

Every time I call a jsp page with this code, I get the following error on WebSphere

```
[err] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: XMLInputFactory ne prend pas en charge cette m□thode : "createXMLStreamReader(Source)".
[err]   at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.msg.StAXMessageProvider.throwUnsupportedOperationException(StAXMessageProvider.java:53)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:590)
[err]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:29)
[err]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:857)
[err]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2572)
[err]   at com.ibm._jsp._test_2D_jack._jspService(_test_2D_jack.java:121)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:101)
[err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
[err]   at [internal classes]
```

Any ideas ?

I'm using the following dependencies in my project :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9.2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Woodstox Parser

If you are using a stand-alone client, you must set these same properties for the client on the java command line as follows:

```
-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory
-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory
-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxEventFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Woodstox parser. If you want to set and configure the parser in the creation of the XmlMapper you can use this code:

```
XMLInputFactory ifactory = new WstxInputFactory();
ifactory.setProperty(...); // Configure parser
XMLOutputFactory ofactory = new WstxOutputFactory();
ofactory.setProperty(...); // Configure parser
XmlFactory xf = new XmlFactory(ifactory, ofactory);

// You can use a module if you need further configuration        
JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);

XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper(xf, module);
```

You can find information here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml#usage